# IF Statement on the VF page to display/hide Related list(s)

Tags: apex, visualforce, if

How can I display/hide related list(s) table on a VF page for a custom object using IF statement?
I am currently displaying 3 separate related lists on my VF page using HTML markup, one of those:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(case.Parent != null, true, false)}">
   <div class="my-table">
            <h3 class="table-title">Related List: 1</h3>
            <div class="row row-header">
              <div class="column"><p>Field1</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field2</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field3</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field4</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field5</p></div>
            </div>

            <apex:repeat value="{!relCases}" var="relCase">
              <div class="row row-data" >  
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field1__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field2__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field3__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field4__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field5__c}</p></div>
              </div>
            </apex:repeat>
   </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I would like to add a IF statement in the VF page, so that, whenever the Lookup field is empty, this complete  should be hidden. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `<apex:outputPanel rendered ="{!condition}"> <!--Content to show --> </apex:outputPanel>` something similar.

Comment: Could you please help me with a sample condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

Just check for the list `size` and we are done, even no need to add the `If` statement here.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! (relCases.size > 0) }">
   <div class="my-table">
            <h3 class="table-title">Related List: 1</h3>
            <div class="row row-header">
              <div class="column"><p>Field1</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field2</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field3</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field4</p></div>
              <div class="column"><p>Field5</p></div>
            </div>

            <apex:repeat value="{!relCases}" var="relCase">
              <div class="row row-data" >  
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field1__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field2__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field3__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field4__c}</p></div>
                <div class="column"><p>{!relCase.field5__c}</p></div>
              </div>
            </apex:repeat>
   </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in a output panel, but to be fair itzmukeshy was correct also, you don't need to do the IF

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered= "{!IF(yourLookup != null, true, false)}">
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I have used this:
`<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(case.Parent != null, true, false)}">`. This is still displaying table with empty rows(row headers were displaying). Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you've done

Comment: Updated the code.

Comment: It looks like you only want to show the related cases `List`, if that case has a Parent so I would actually check to see if the `relCases.isEmpty` (null or size) rather than case.Parent.  I don't see anything wrong with what you did but you should put some System.debug();  in your controller to see what may be happening